# How should one transform a variable in which the further away from 0, the more significant it is?

Tags: logistic, data-transformation, feature-engineering, exploratory-data-analysis

Let's say you have a variable that ranges from -inf to +inf.  The further you get away from 0, the more effect you think it has on the response.  I am doing a logistic regression by the way.  And basically, the closer the variable is close to +/-inf, my hypothesis is that the more likely a 1 is to occur.  I can take the absolute value, but then we have the issue of the random variable being bounded to unbounded from 0 to +inf.

Should I normalize the absolute value of the random variable?

Thanks!

Comment: Wasn't it unbounded in the first place?

Comment: @gunes I think it's the boundedness that worries him, 0 from below.

Comment: Have you tried the absolute value transformation? How do the model diagnostics look?

Comment: Did you try to spline the variable? Can you show us some plots, sample sizes, and general context? ...